# jQuery, Triggering event from Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Please take a look at the following code and fiddle.

***CODE***

```
$("#enable").click(function(e) {
    if (!$("#enable").data('isOn')) {
        $("#holder").find('.clickable').each(function(d) {
            $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');
            $(this).addClass('clickEnabled');
        });
        $("#enable").data('isOn', true);
    } else {
        $("#holder").find('.clickable').each(function(d) {
            $(this).css('border', '');
            $(this).removeClass('clickEnabled');
        });
        $("#enable").data('isOn', false);

    }

});

$(".clickEnabled").click(function(e) {
    alert('clicked');
});
```

***Fiddle:*** http://jsfiddle.net/qAuwt/

I am basically trying to toggle a "clickEnabled" class on elements when a button is pressed.  The toggling is working as the border is changing however the clickEnabled class is not responding to click events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no `.clickEnabled` elements when you set the event handler. You can still catch the click event, though:

```
$(document).on("click", ".clickEnabled", function(){
    alert("Hello, world!");
});​
```

Comment: Isn't that inefficient due to the fact that all clicks on the document traverse the dom tree every single time?

Comment: You don't have to do it this way.  See my answer for an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
$(".clickEnabled").click(function (e) {
    alert('clicked');   
});
```

To:

```
$(".clickable").click(function (e) {
    if ( $(this).hasClass("clickEnabled") )
    {
        alert('clicked');   
    }
});
```

As @araxanas mentioned, the `.clickEnabled` don't exist on load.  So I switched the selector to `.clickable`, which do. However, you only want to handle the click when they're enabled.  That's why I've added the conditional.  It'll only alert if the clicked element has the `clickEnabled` class.

Also, it might help to move the css out of javascript, that way you can see visually if the class is there or not, see my updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qAuwt/7/).

Comment: I like your answer due to the efficiency but it will not work with my code as I bind and unbind events.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that when page loaded, the click event handler binds to no elements (because there is no element with class 'clickEnabled').

The solution is to change the .click() method to .live() method:

```
$(".clickEnabled").live('click', function (e) {
    alert('clicked');
});
```

Comment: `live` is deprecated in jQuery >1.7.